# Launch4j Icon Image Quality

Tags: java, image, icons, launch4j, ico

I am currently using Launch4j to convert my JAR files to EXEs. While I was doing this, I added an image icon (ico). Now when I compile the program and the EXE is made, the icon image quality isn't great. But then if I rename the file, the quality is fine. Can someone tell me what is going on here and how to make it so that I don't have to rename the file to have good icon image quality? Thanks.

Comment: Does your icon have multiple resolutions, 16, 24, 32, 64?

Comment: I used a PNG to ICO converter, the image has a native resolution of 512x512. I'm guessing this is a no to your question, and I would need help  because I don't know how to make an icon have multiple resolutions.

Comment: First, crack open you favourite image editor, creat multiple different resolutions of you image, I like having 16, 24, 32, 64 and 128, save these as separate files. Use something like [image4j](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/) which will allow you to write multiple images to an ico

Answer (score 0):

Use [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) to create an icon with multiple resolutions.

References:

- [Creating an .ico file with multiple sizes - web application](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17257/creating-an-ico-file-with-multiple-sizes-web-application)
- [Make several PNGs into one ICO file [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808600/make-several-pngs-into-one-ico-file)
- [Creating a multi-resolution favicon including transparency with the GIMP](https://www.catalyst.net.nz/news/creating-multi-resolution-favicon-including-transparency-gimp)